# Error when I specify multiple options in my PHP bash script

Tags: bash, php, email, pipe

```
#!/usr/bin/php -d register_argc_argv=1
...
```

At the top of my PHP script, I have the above and it works well. However, I need to add another `-q` and changed it to `#!/usr/bin/php -q -d register_argc_argv=1`.

But it results with the error

```
The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ pipe to |/home/user/email_pipe.php /home/user
       generated by email@example.com ------

Error in argument 1, char 3: option not found 
Usage: php-cgi [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php-cgi <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -b <address:port>|<port> Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
```

Any idea? My script has the correct LF endings.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer: `#!/usr/bin/php -qd register_argc_argv=1`

I'm pretty sure I tried this before posting, somehow it gave me the impression things were not working.

Also, multiple parameters are not supported based on my further googling

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399690/multiple-arguments-in-shebang

Hope this helps anyone who is struggling with email piping